# Android - Dagger 2: Unable to provide a single for dependencies provided via Application Component

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, singleton, dagger-2

The dependencies provided via the application component of the app do not have a single instance. 
I have the following code:

```
    @Component (modules = AppModule.class)
        public interface AppComponent {

        SharedPreferences  getSharedPreferences();

        }

        @Module
        public class AppModule {

            private Context appContext;
            private String prefFile;

            public AppModule(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull String prefFile) {
                this.appContext = appContext;
                this.prefFile = prefFile;
            }

            @Provides
            public SharedPreferences providePreferences(){
                return new AppSharedPreferences(appContext, prefFile);
            }

        }

@Singleton
public class AppSharedPreferences implements SharedPreferences{

public AppSharedPreferences(Context appContext, String prefFile)

//Some code

}




        public class AppApplication extends Application {

            private AppComponent appComponent;
            private InteractorsComponent interactorsComponent;

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();


        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(getApplicationContext(), "PREF_STORE_NAME")).build();


                interactorsComponent = DaggerInteractorsComponent.builder().appComponent(appComponent).build();
            }

            public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
                return appComponent;
            }

            public InteractorsComponent getInteractorsComponent() {
                return interactorsComponent;
            }
        }



        @Module
        abstract class InteractorsModule {

            @Singleton
            @Binds
            abstract InteractorA provideInteractorA(AppInteractorA interactor);

    @Singleton
            @Binds
            abstract InteractorB provideInteractorB(AppInteractorB interactor);
        }

        @Singleton
        @Component (modules = InteractorsModule.class, dependencies = AppComponent.class)
        public interface InteractorsComponent {

            InteractorA getInteractorA();

        InteractorB getInteractorB();

        }

        @Singleton
        class AppInteractorA implements InteractorA {

            private  AppSharedPreferences pref;

            @Inject
            public AppInteractor(@NonNull AppSharedPreferences pref) {
                this.pref = pref;
            }

        //Other overridden methods
        }

        @Singleton
        class AppInteractorB implements InteractorB {

            private  AppSharedPreferences pref;

            @Inject
            public AppInteractor(@NonNull AppSharedPreferences pref) {
                this.pref = pref;
            }

        //Other overridden methods
        }
```

Now, InteractorA and InteractorB to be injected in someother classes. 
InteractorA and InteractorB instances themselves are singleton where ever they are injected. But of object of InteractorA and object of InteractorB, a different instance of SharedPreferences class is provided. So InteractorA has a different instance of SharedPreferences and InteractorB has a different instance of SharedPreferences.

Could someone help to make sure that both InteractorA and InteractorB have the same instance of SharedPreferences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
  // ...
  @Provides
  public SharedPreferences providePreferences(){
    return new AppSharedPreferences(appContext, prefFile);
  }
}
```

Though AppSharedPreferences is annotated with `@Singleton`, you're calling its constructor yourself, which means that Dagger can't guarantee that there's only one SharedPreferences instance in your application. This means that you'll get a new AppSharedPreferences instance whenver you inject SharedPreferences, including through the InteractorsComponent component dependency.

You should mark `providePreferences` with @Singleton, or use an `@Inject` constructor on AppSharedPreferences so that Dagger can manage its `@Singleton` behavior.